# Unable to resolve "./GestureHandlerRootView

Tags: react-native

I tried to create a simple route(installing all packages including this), but I get an error Unable to resolve "./GestureHandlerRootView" from "node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\GestureHandler.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Main } from '../screens/Main';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Main
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);
export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

and the app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppContainer } from './src/navigation/AppNavigation';
import { Main } from './src/screens/Main';

export default function App() {


  return <AppContainer />;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new update has just been released.
Reinstall the library to get the new version 1.5.5.
It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just had this issue, initializing a fresh RN app.

I took a look to my old projects, and I saw that react-native-gesture-handler is updated to 1.5.4 now..  After some search, trying to fix this problem, I just downgraded to version 1.5.3 of gesture handler, and follow up with the normal installation.

I'm also using react-navigation and react-navigation-stack. If possible I'll try again with the updated version.

Comment: works for me, I just downgraded my version removing the "^" from package, and reinstall

Answer (score 1):

Just had same problem.  GestureHanderRootView.js was missing from node modules for some reason.  For now, I just created the file and copied from here and all was fine:

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/blob/master/GestureHandlerRootView.js

Answer (score 0):

In my case GestureHanderRootView.js existed, but it was cached in gradle.
I used this from root direction :

`cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew :app:bundleRelease`